# Count number of elements in list after slideup/slidedown

Tags: jquery

I use this function to select elements in a list :

```
function listFilter(list, input) { 
  $(input)
  .change( function () {
    var filter = $(this).val();
    if(filter) {
      $(list).find('a:not(:Contains(' + filter + '))').parent().slideUp();
      $(list).find('a:Contains(' + filter + ')').parent().slideDown();
    } else {
      $(list).find('li').slideDown();
    }        
    return false;
  })
.keyup( function () {
    // fire the above change event after every letter
    $(this).change();

});
```

}

This works fine but now I would like to trigger to search function in the data underneath if the selection narrows down to one element left in the list.

I have been trying .filter(':visible') on the list object and on the list.children but nothing gives me the correct number of elements left after the user has entered some text.

Something like alert($(list).children().filter(':visible').length); but I always get the initial number of elements shown.