# I can't find live count of elements after running script multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of elements. Upon clicking a link, I want to filter the elements by a class. (so far it's okay). The trouble: if there are no elements with that class, I want to print a message saying that.

```
$('.filterEventsLinks a').click(function(){
     // count total number of events
     var evCount = $('.singleEvent').length;

     // a list of comma-separated class names to filter are stored in the data attribute of the fired element
     // for example: <a data-category="kids,teens,adults" href="#"></a>
     var cats = $(this).data('category');

     // split into an array
     var catArr = cats.split(',');

    // loop through
    for(var i in catArr) {
        var cat = '.CAT-' + catArr[i];

        // hide things that do not have this category
        $('.singleEvent').not(cat).slideUp(200);
        // show things that do
        $(cat).slideDown(200);

    }

    // count number of remaining visible elements
    var evCount = $('.singleEvent').filter(':visible').length;

    // do more...
});
```

Everything here works as expected *except* that last line. The last line that doesn't seem to work. It always returns the number of elements that exist, not the number that are currently visible.

Same problem listed in this SO question: [Count number of elements in list after slideup/slidedown](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15765690/362769)

Comment: I don't know about the actual implementation, but `slideUp`/`slideDown` will most likely _start_ the transition. You count the elements too early, you have to wait until they've hidden. Have you tried `setTimeout(function(){console.log($('.singleEvent').filter(':visible').length);},1000);` or something similar?

Comment: @Zeta...exactly right.  You might want to look at jQuery promises.

Comment: @Zeta 's right, confirmed in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/WzZq4/1/

Comment: @Zeta has the perfect answer. When the `slideUp()` is changed to `hide()` it works perfectly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of looping through the categories in the data-attribute, you can build a selector to match them all at once:

```
$('.filterEventsLinks a').click(function(){    
     var cats = $(this).data('category');
     //create a selector to match the categories
     var selector = '.CAT-' + cats.split(',').join(',.CAT-');

     //get filtered elements
     var $elems = $(selector);
     // hide things that do not have this category
     $('.singleEvent').not($elems).slideUp(200);
     // show things that do
     $elems.slideDown(200);

     // count number of remaining visible elements
     var evCount = $elems.length;
});
```

Comment: +1 for addressing the issue rather than just fixing the existing code

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to count the elements after the animation has completed.  When the elements are animating they are still visible, or you could just keep the elements in a collection and count that :

```
$('.filterEventsLinks a').click(function(){
     var evCount = $('.singleEvent').length,
         cats    = $(this).data('category').split(','),
         elems   = $([]);

     $.each(cats, function(_, cat) {
        var _cat = $('.CAT-' + cat);
        $('.singleEvent').not(_cat).slideUp(200);
        _cat.slideDown(200);
        elems = elems.add(_cat);
    }

    // you're sliding all .singleEvent elements except "elems" up, so just count
    // the elements in "elems" instead, as that should be the visible ones
    var evCount = elems.length;
});
```

Comment: But after the loop you'll only get the count of the last class

Comment: @koala_dev - I guess you would, changed it to add the elements in every iteration to a common collection

Answer (score 0):

Instead of counting the currently visible elements, I just used the same criteria as used earlier, and counted those, i.e.:

```
$(cat).length;
```

Which was a much simpler way around this whole thing.

Comment: how did that fit inside your loop? you would need a "sum" variable to increment on each iteration, I believe an approach without a loop, like the one I suggested would actually be simpler plus more efficient

Comment: @koala_dev, I ended up also doing what you suggested regardless of this answer.